# Organize Includes of Eclipse CDT 8.2 not working with inheritance

Tags: eclipse, ide, include, eclipse-cdt

I recently switched to Eclipse Kepler with CDT 8.2 for my C++ development in order to use the new "Organize Includes" feature which is already a huge relief.

I experienced problems when using it with inheritance though. The command always removes the header of the base class. I assume this is a bug because my indexer settings seem to be correct as everything else works fine.

Anyone else experienced this behavior and knows a was around it?

best regards
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Ok I understand that the bug was fixed with this commit: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421398

Does anyone know how to build and install CDT from source or do I have to wait until a package is provided via the eclipse update mechanism?